# Strongloop append object

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, strongloop

I have MySQL table with column type JSON

```
{
"type": "1",
"local": "1",
"maker": "1"
}
```

I want append the the JSON array

```
[{
"type": "1",
"local": "1",
"maker": "1"
},
{
"type": "2",
"local": "2",
"maker": "2"
}]
```

How i use Strongloop to append that ? I used the method PUT/ID and it replaced my array like

```
{
"type": "2",
"local": "2",
"maker": "2"
}
```

I dont want to GET/ID my array and merge the new and send de PUT.

Is possible to apeend ?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing you have `JavaScript` selected as a tag you can do it in JavaScript using `Array.prototype.concat()`

See the [**Array.prototype.concat()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) documentation for more details.

```js
var x = {
  "type": "1",
  "local": "1",
  "maker": "1"
};

var y = {
  "type": "2",
  "local": "2",
  "maker": "2"
}

var result = [].concat(x).concat(y);

console.log(result);
```